# Ajuda com formulário JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Olá, imagino que minha dúvida seja simples mas ainda não achei nada nos fóruns da vida (provavelmente por não usar os termos corretos na busca).

Estou criando um formulário para estudantes em JavaFX gerando arquivos fxml com Scene Builder, ele é separado em duas partes uma dados gerais e outra para específicos. Nesse caso, uma parte para os dados pessoais do aluno a outra tem dados sobre o curso do mesmo. Considerando que existem cinco cursos, os campos referentes a cada um serão diferentes.

Gerei um fxml com os campos das informações gerais e deixei um pane vazio para incorporar um fxml referente a um dos cursos.

Meu objetivo é oferecer uma tela ao usuário com cinco botões, um para cada curso, quando ele clicar em um o formulário completo é mostrado.

Se alguém souber de algo que possa me ajudar, favor compartilhar. Muito obrigado.

---

Adicionando informações

Não estou com meu computador por isso vou ter de usar outro exemplo, mas as imagens abaixo explicam melhor a situação.

Nesse projeto o usuário pode fazer uma queixa alimentar, animal ou diversa, todas elas partilham de informações comuns que podem ser observadas na parte superior do formulário a imagem abaixo.

[image: queixa - formulário geral]

Na parte de baixo, há um anchor pane vazio que gostaria de carrega-lo com um  formulário específico com o abaixo. O Stack Overflow não me permitiu inserir mais de duas imagens.

[image: queixa alimentar]

Código da classe de controle da queixa (formulário geral):

```
public class QueixaController implements Initializable, IControlledScreen {

private ScreensController controller;
@FXML RadioButton choice;
@FXML DatePicker date;
@FXML ChoiceBox address;
@FXML TextArea descriptions;
@FXML TextArea observations;
@FXML AnchorPane pane;

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {    
}    
/**Método usado na transição de telas
@Override
public void setScreenParent(ScreensController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
}    
}
```

Código para classe de controle da queixa alimentar:

```
public class QueixaAlimentarController implements Initializable {
@FXML TextField commensal;
@FXML TextField sick;
@FXML TextField deads;
@FXML TextField inHoslpital;

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}     
}
```

Minha dúvida é: há alguma maneira de codificar para que o formulário de dados gerais incorpore um formulário de dados específicos evitando criar um completo para cada tipo de queixa, considerando que vou ter uma tela para que o usuário escolha que tipo de queixa fazer?

Comment: Sua pergunta está legal, mas é um tanto difícil de responder sem que você tenha postado o que você já fez ou tentou fazer. Você poderia postar o que você já fez, até para facilitar o processo de se escrever uma resposta?

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta, imagino que esteja mais claro agora mas se ainda não estiver, me avise que tento arrumar. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Sua pergunta agora parece estar boa. Dei o meu voto para reabrir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bem, você precisa deixar um pane(pode ser HBox,VBox,Pane etc) vazio, na área que você for adicionar. Depois use o seguinte código :

```
paneVazio.getChildren().setAll(
    FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("arquivo.fxml")) 
);
```

Não tive tempo de testar, mas pelo visto é assim que se faz mesmo.

Comment: Já tem um tempo que mexi nesse projeto dessas classes, vou procurar e testar.  Obrigado.

Comment: O tópico é antigo e havia me esquecido que havia feito a pergunta, mas de fato essa é a melhor abordagem que conheço para resolver esse problema. Obrigado pela resposta.